# After updating of HAXM, emulator with Android API 28 doesn't start up

Tags: android, emulation, intel, hardware-acceleration, haxm

I have the next issue. After updated HAXM up to 7.2.0 android emulator in android studio with version API 28 dont start up. I cant run the emulator. I am using laptop on Intel processor, i7. Virtualization is on. Before updating it worked. After updating, I can run emulator just if Turned On Software acceleration. If Hardware - impossible to run. If use x86_64 instead x86 I get black screen on emulator and errors in logcat:

```
06-18 08:13:42.256 1632-1632/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Error while linking shaders:
06-18 08:13:42.529 1632-1632/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Error while compiling

 shader: 
    attribute vec4 position;
    uniform mat4 projection;
    uniform mat4 texture;
    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = projection * position;
    }

    `�
06-18 08:13:42.531 1632-1632/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Error while compiling shader: 
    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec4 color;
    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor.rgb = color.rgb;
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
    }

    ����
```

If use x86 then emulator is stuck on the place:
[Emulator stuck screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87lxl.png)

With error in logcat.

```
06-18 08:18:06.429 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getService package_native failed
06-18 08:19:06.431 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:20:06.432 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:21:06.433 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:22:06.434 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:23:06.436 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:24:06.437 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:25:06.437 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:26:06.438 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:27:06.439 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:28:06.439 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:29:06.441 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-18 08:30:06.442 1712-1750/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
```

Ask you to help me with this, if someone knows how to fix it, please.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and solved it by doing so: Tools > Adv Manager > right click on the down arrow of the emulator concerned in the Actions column > then Wipe Data

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by updating Android Emulator to lower version, in my case that was 27.1.12 version. After that, all works fine. As I said above, all tools are updated to recent, and just AE was restored to lower. I copied folder "emulator" from one AndroidSDK folder, and replaced it another.

Comment: Sorry, but not. I still face the issue from time to time. And the main thing, is that the same parameters (software versions and settings for emulator/ android studio) are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I needed to test my app in Android 28. It was fixed updating the android studio to the 3.1.3 Version

Comment: Thanks for your answer.