# Android API 28 emulator won't start

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I've got big problems getting an AVD emulator to start with API 28 and Android Studio 3.1.3 on my Lenovo X1 Carbon 4th Gen (VT on). Other APIs like 27 works without problems but if I try to start an emulator with API 28, I get the following errors:

```
06-19 19:30:38.284 1734-1824/? E/storaged: getService package_native failed
06-19 19:31:38.288 1734-1824/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
06-19 19:32:38.291 1734-1824/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
```

...with a stuck Android logo.

Things I've already tried to fix the problem:

- Reinstalled Android Studio
- Reinstalled Windows and Android Studio
- Reinstalled HAXM (and installed older versions)
- Stopped Services for Windows Defender and SmartScreen
- Changed Settings for the emulator like VM HEAP SIZE...
- Installed an older version of Android Studio
- Reinstalled emulator
- BIOS and Storage Updates
- Copied the "Emulator" Folder from another Computer where it works

But nothing works and I don't know what to do anymore. It's the same problem another user had but he fixed his: [After updating of HAXM, emulator with Android API 28 doesn't start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905333/after-updating-of-haxm-emulator-with-android-api-28-doesnt-start-up).

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: Nope...i use the API 27 now on this particular Laptop

Comment: Are you still having the issue or did you get it started? Ours is stalled on the Google logo screen too. Just sits there. Even tried waiting an hour. 27 works fine but 28 just sits.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I've tried the x86 & x86_64 Google images, and API 28 Emulator will just sit on the Google logo screen forever.  All lower emulators work